# Не устанавливается модуль PyAutoGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

У меня Windows, использую среду PyCharm.

Я в терминале прописываю: "pip install pyautogui".

Начинается установка, но вскоре вылетает такая ошибка:"The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source."

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы ввели "pip install pyautogui" в терминал PyCharm -
то попробуйте ввести его в командную строку cmd,
я попробовал и у меня не было никаких проблем.

Comment: Там после ввода:''pip не является внутренней или внешней командой..."

Comment: Вы можете также добавить нужный вам пакет использовав "+" в Project Interpreter (File | Settings...), где Вы можете найти пакет просто введя "pyautogui"